# connected sets in a topology are the intervals

Tags: general-topology

Suppose we have $\mathbb{R}$ with the Euclidean topology $T$. If $D$ is a dense set in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbb{R} \setminus D $ is also dense in $\mathbb{R}$, consider the collection $\mathcal{B}$ of sets $\{x\} \cup (D \cap U) $ where $x \in U$ and $U \in T$.

I was able to prove that $\mathcal{B}$ is a base for a topology $T^*$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

I want to prove that the connected sets of $\mathbb{R}$ in $T^*$ are the intervals. But I have to clue how to prove this.

I started by supposing that a connected set $S$ is not an interval, then there exist $x,y \in S$ and $z \notin S$ such that $x<z<y$. But I'm confused how to proceed.

Comment: Now, you could try to show that $S$ is disconnected via the definition of $S$.  Find nonempty, disjoint, open sets that cover $S$.  For instance, let $S_+$ be the elements of $S$ greater than $Z$ and $S_-$ the elements of $S$ less than $z$.  Note that these are formed from intersecting $S$ with open sets in the Euclidean topology.

Comment: @MichaelBurr but how do we know that those topologies are open in $T^*$? And if they are does that conclude the proof immediately?

Comment: They are not open in $T^\ast$, but $T^\ast$ is built upon open sets of $T$, which these are.

Comment: @MichaelBurr wait but doesn't that invalidate your statement of a separation? Don't those sets have to be open in the chosen topology? Also in my last comment I meant "sets" instead of "topologies"

Comment: I meant to say that it is not clear if they are open or not, a priori, in $T^\ast$.  It does not invalidate the argument because there might be another open set which has the correct intersection.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be a set which is not an interval.  Then, there exist $x,y\in S$ and $z\not\in S$ such that $x<z<y$.  Let $S_+=S\cap (z,\infty)$ and $S_-=S\cap(-\infty,z)$.  Then, observe that $S=S_+\cup S_-$.

Our goal is to show that $S_+$ and $S_-$ can be written as $S\cap U$ and $S\cap V$, respectively, for $U,V\in\mathcal{T}^\ast$.

Let $\mathcal{A}_+=\{\{a\}\cup (D\cap(z,\infty)):a>z\}$.  This is a collection of open sets and $\bigcup_{U\in\mathcal{A}_+}U=(z,\infty)$ (can you explain why?).  Since the arbitrary union of open sets is open, it follows that $(z,\infty)$ is open in $\mathcal{T}^\ast$.

A similar construction can be done for $(-\infty,z)$.

Putting this all together, we get that $S$ is separated.

Note that this does not prove that all intervals are connected, only that if a set is connected, then it must be an interval.

Comment: How would one go about proving that all intervals are connected?

Comment: I would use the definition and ask that question as a new post.

Comment: link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4414423/proving-intervals-are-connected-in-a-topology